# dispatch async hangs on main thread while encoding image

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

So I am taking this UIImage data and and converting to a string in base64. the problem is that it hangs on the UI thread whilst converting and I am not sure why.

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage*)image{


    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
    [self.spinnerOutlet setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.spinnerOutlet startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

        // Convert image
        NSData *myData = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[myData bytes]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI

            [self showSuccessAlertView:@"Success!" message:@"Submitting Image..."];
            snapShotInBase64 = myString;
            [self sendImagePostRequest];
        });

    });



}
```

Comment: What about `sendImagePostRequest` ? Is this method running on main thread ?

Comment: You are right... This resolves the hanging. It appears to be not the conversion to base64 but the fact that I need it for a post request... This now leads on to a new problem.... I need to make that post request asynchronously whilst delegates get back calls from delegate methods once the post is done....

Comment: Just surround the `sendImagePostRequest` into another `dispatch_async` on your queue or on the global queue`. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage*)image{

    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
    [self.spinnerOutlet setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.spinnerOutlet startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

        // Convert image
        NSData *myData = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[myData bytes]];
        snapShotInBase64 = myString;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI
            [self showSuccessAlertView:@"Success!" message:@"Submitting Image..."];
        });
    });

    dispatch_barrier_async(myQueue, ^{
        [self sendImagePostRequest];
    }); 
}
```

or

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage*)image{

        dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
        [self.spinnerOutlet setAlpha:0.0f];
        [self.spinnerOutlet startAnimating];
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

            // Convert image
            NSData *myData = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
            NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[myData bytes]];
            snapShotInBase64 = myString;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update the UI
                [self showSuccessAlertView:@"Success!" message:@"Submitting Image..."];
                dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
                      [self sendImagePostRequest];
                });
            });
        }); 
    }
```

hope will help. If you upload image in server, why you don`t use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library